# Primefaces dataTable iterate list inside list by index

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

In my JSF example I am getting a list which contains two lists:
`One for result returned from DB and another containing list of column header from DB`.
 In the first list(containing result) has row data per index.
e.g. **

> transaction.transactionsList[0][1]

contain one row data in below code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{transaction.transactionsList[0]}" var="tran">
    <p:columns value="#{transaction.transactionsList[1]}" var="column"
        sortBy="#{tran[column.property]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{tran[column.property]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Please advise how to iterate based on length of list containing data and based on index over nested list, like:

### transaction.transactionsList[0][i]

Comment: So what's the problem? `transactionsList[0]`? Since it's a List, do `transactionsList.get(0)`.

Comment: @vsevolod:  the question contains contradictory info. Especially the [1] is not a nested list while i think it is meant to be one

Comment: @Kukeltje, as I understood it, `transactionsList[0]` is rows of data and `transactionsList[1]` is metadata describing columns in those rows. Instead of "nested list" it should be "nested loop".

Comment: Yes but in the question OP also posted `transaction.transactionsList[0][1]` which **is** nested... hence my 'confusion'...

Comment: `transactionsList` is an outer list, `transactionsList[0]` is a nested list with row data, `transactionsList[0][1]` is the second row. `transactionsList` itself is wrong of course, it contains two unrelated entries - it shouldn't be a list at all...